# error: package org.opencv.android does not exist

Tags: ros, mapping, ptam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I’m working on a project to view 3D objects using PTAM library. When executing the project, I get the error: “error: package org.opencv.android does not exist." What would be the solution for this? OpenCV  downloaded the android SDK and have included the project. But I got the same error. What would be the solution for this?
Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214627/error:-package-org.opencv.android-does-not-exist/) by [Hakan Bey](https://answers.ros.org/users/23263/hakan-bey/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-07-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

try this  [stack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22516291/how-to-package-and-link-opencv-binares-and-opencv-java-sdk-for-android-studio)

Greet
Anton

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2015-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1